# Не работает пример изменения границ формы

Tags: delphi

Сделано на основе [примера кода](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/draw_on_form_border.html). Вот что получилось у меня:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
 procedure WMNCPaint(var Msg : TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
 Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.WMNCPaint(var Msg: TWMNCPaint);
    var
  dc: hDc;
  Pen: hPen;
  OldPen: hPen;
  OldBrush: hBrush;
begin
  inherited;
  dc := GetWindowDC(Handle);
  msg.Result := 1;
  Pen := CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));
     OldPen := SelectObject(dc, Pen);
  OldBrush := SelectObject(dc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
 Rectangle(dc, 5,5, Form1.Width, Form1.Height);
 SelectObject(dc, OldBrush);
 SelectObject(dc, OldPen);
 DeleteObject(Pen);
 ReleaseDC(Handle, Canvas.Handle);
end;

end.
```

У меня delphi 7, windows 7,  в итоге ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom Window Frame Using DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195).

Answer (score 0):

Может потому, что вы освобождаете не тот хэндл?

```
ReleaseDC(Handle, Canvas.Handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ReleaseDC(Handle, dc);
```

Comment: Нет, дело в том, что у меня виновус 7. Если я отключаю тему windows aero, то все работает. Досадно. А как с aero сделать чтоб работало? Хотя врят ли кто ответит...